# How to remove the data from MySQL DB from node when the scheduled time limit expire

Tags: mysql, node.js, push-notification, scheduled-tasks

I would need to remove some data from the MySQL DB when the expire time has arrived.
Like, expire the cookie value on the server-side when user session time has arrived. It's like an automatic action. It's needs to do even the customer was not online. When he was back to the online he needs to login again. And it needs to do some works like reminder action. User can fix some time to bring some reminder notification. On that time server needs to fetch some data from the MySQL DB and sent it to the customer through the push notification automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1. Add a column in your table to store the expiry date/time using default systime + expiry.  You want the time to be generated by the DB and not your app code, so it will be exact.
2. Index this column with BTree, not Hash.  You need this index.
3. Write a stored procedure to delete rows < current system time.
4. Create a mysql scheduled event to run every 1 minute to run your stored procedure.